# Azure W2K12R2 VM only accessible by app with firewall off

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, azure

I am trying to access a new Azure based VM with a timesheet app from a local client using the downloaded Azure VPN client.

The Azure VPN issued client is installed on my local machine and works fine so I can access all shares etc.

If the VM firewall is turned off then I can access the VM based server app no problem.

If the VM firewall is turned on, and there is a rule present to open ports on the firewall created by the timesheet server app itself on installation, the timesheet client app cannot access the timesheet server.

From the firewall log it is clear the packets are dropped. e.g.

> 2016-05-24 09:24:53 DROP TCP 192.168.0.5 192.168.116.4 51474 8052 48 S 145448833 0 8192 - - - RECEIVE.

Tried explicitly allowing 8052 and TCP instead of the "Any" option in the rule but still no joy.

Following Event shown in event viewer.

> Windows Firewall was unable to notify the user that it blocked an application >from accepting incoming connections on the network.
>
> Reason:        The application is a system service
>   Application Path:  C:\program files (x86)\senomix\senomix timesheets server service\nt_service\timesheets server.exe
>
> IP Version: IPv6
>
> Protocol:   TCP
>
> Port:       8052
>
> Process Id: 8128
>
> User:       SYSTEM

Can anybody give me any pointers as to where to look? I've run a Windows Small business server for a number of years and happily administered that but the Azure dimension has introduced a lot of uncertainty for me. Any pointers gratefully received.

Comment: works with firewall off, doesn't work with firewall on - must be the firewall. try manually creating the rule

Comment: Thanks for responding. Have tried to manually add the firewall rule (windows firewall) and makes no difference.

Comment: turn logging on the firewall for dropped requests.  See if you see anything in event viewer

Comment: Thanks @CtrlDot I've added the detail that resulted to the original post.

Comment: Can you try removing the "program" restriction on the firewall rule?  I just want to see if it will work.  Sometimes the application you run isn't the application that requests the port to be open / handles the traffic

Comment: @CtrlDot, sorry for lack of response - offsite doing something else. Unless I am misunderstanding you then the rule dialogue window wom't permit me to not have a selection for program. The choices under the Programs and Services tab are Programs - and you can select either "All programs that meet the specified conditions", or "This program" and you can browse to a particular program. Must have one or the other. On the same page there is the option to (also) add application  packages and services. The self generated rule adds the Timeseheet Server services to the rule.

Comment: You can generate windows firewall rules without specifying a program.  Just specify a port

Comment: Aaah. had forgotten about using the wizard. This did indeed allow me to specify a new rule against a port alone. That did the trick. I can now get to the Timesheet server. Thanks to @CtrlDot for persisting.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the application restriction on the firewall rule and restrict it only to port.  Once you get it working, try running

```
netstat -anob
```

To determine which application is actually opening the port.  You can use that information to reconfigure the rule for application support (should you require the added security benefit).

Comment: Ok. Results as follows:
>C:\Windows\system32>netstat -anob | findstr 8052
>TCP    0.0.0.0:8052           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8128
>TCP    192.168.116.4:8052     192.168.0.10:63024     ESTABLISHED     8128
>TCP    [::]:8052              [::]:0                 LISTENING       8128

Process 8128 is the original "timesheets server.exe". Thanks for all the help @CtrlDot. A newbie Stack Overflow type I've accepted this answer and jacked up the points. No idea if that is too much or too little.

Comment: ...and as a newbie I can't change points!

Comment: I've tried doing some looking on how the windows firewall does program detection.  I suggest asking another question surrounding that so you can get a better idea of how to build that rule (with the program included).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your "automatically created" rule at installation corresponds to the real port opening requierement of the application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have checked the automatically added firewall rule and the settings all seem sensible (to the limits of my knowledge). The rule allows connection by anyone and to the particular service  (timesheet server). Protocols and ports allows any protocol and all ports. I've tried changing to TCS and UDP in turn and referring to the specific port 8052 as required by the server and there is no change in behaviour.